# Login Não funciona mesmo colocando a senha certa

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]         O problema no caso é que independente de a senha estar errada ou certa ele diz que as credenciais estão erradas, e não faz o login
//código php

```
   if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    //variaveis que serão usadas no sistema.
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["username"]);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["password"]);
    //verificação se existe um usuario com este nome no sistema.
    if(empty($username))
    {
        array_push($erros, "O Usuário é necessário!");
    }
    //verificação da senha do usuario escolhido
    if(empty($password)){
        array_push($erros, "Uma senha é necessária");
    }
    if(count($erros) === 0){
        //query SQL que irá ser usada
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email=? OR username=? LIMIT 1";
    
        //declaração e preparação da query
        $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);

        // declaração dos pontos de interrogação da query
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $username);

        // declaração de execução da query
        $stmt->execute();

        //armazena o resultado da declaração em uma variável
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        //extração de um usuário do resultado
        $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
        
        //verificação se a senha está certa
        if (password_verify($password, $user['password']))
        {
            $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
            $_SESSION['verified'] = $user['verified'];

            $_SESSION['message'] = "Agora você está logado!";
            $_SESSION['alert-class'] = "alert-success";
            header('location: index.php');
            exit();
        } else{
            $erros['login_fail'] = "Credenciais erradas!";
        }
    }
     
        //código do formulário de login

                    <form method="POST" action="login.php" class="box">
                <?php include('erros.php'); ?>
                <h1>login</h1>
                <input type="text" name ="username" value="<?php echo $username ?>" placeholder="LOGIN">

                <input type="password" name ="password" placeholder="SENHA">

                <input type="submit" name="login" value="FAZER LOGIN"> 

                
                <h3><a href="./forgot.php">Esqueceu a Senha</a></h3>
                <h3><a href="./create.php">Criar Conta</a></h3>
            </form>
```

Comment: Olá! Antes de `if (password_verify($password, $user['password']))` verifique se `$user['password']` tem valor. Pode fazer um `echo` ou `var_dump` por exemplo.

Comment: Outro ponto importante é saber como foi gerada a password que está na base de dados.

Comment: eu usei o echo antes do "if" e realmente bate com a senha do banco de dados, mas por algum motivo não entra na parte de login do código e entra no else

Comment: Verifica se a senha foi salva com md5. Se for o caso voce deve converter a senha para md5 primeiro.

Comment: Se a senha bate com a do banco de dados (e vc conseguiu verificar isso) então está mesmo errado.

Comment: eu usei o ´password_hash()` pra fazer a criptografia da senha, e no caso do `password_verify` ele utilizaria o hash e a senha que o usuário escreveu para verificar, mas não tá funcionando

Comment: Tenta atualizar a senha no BD usando novamente o `password_hash`.

Comment: Mostre exatamente o seu código onde você está criptografando a senha por favor